# Exibir lista de dados por ordem de data. Firebase

Tags: android

Olá, estou com uma barreira de como trazer os dados do firebase e exibir em ordem por data, exibir do mais recente para o mais velho, atualmente os dados estão sendo exibido de forma padrao no firebase.

```
database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getDatabase().child("comentarios");
        //Listener para recuperar os comentarios
    valueEventListenerComentarios = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //Limpar lista
            listaComentarios.clear();
                //Listar comentários
            for (DataSnapshot dados: dataSnapshot.getChildren() ){
                Comentario comentario = dados.getValue( Comentario.class );
                listaComentarios.add( comentario );
            }
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    };
```

Comment: Dps do child, você bota `.orderBy`, é algo assim, só digita `order` já deve aparecer o resto, aí você coloca por qual campo que quer que seja feito a sort

Comment: Isso, mais já fiz uma Query, mesmo assim, ele não deixa de ordem decrescente.

Answer (score 1):

Depois do child você coloca .orderByChild("")

```
database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getDatabase().child("comentarios").orderByChild("Referência_da_data_no_firebase");
```

Comment: Não, da erro, eu já havia tentado assim.

Comment: database = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getDatabase().child("comentarios");
query = database.orderByChild("idComentario");

EStou tentando asssim, mais mesmo assim ele não vem em ordem.
p idComentario estou passando o timestamp, mais não vem na ordem do mais recente para o mais antigo.